# How do I get a program to continuously input new information from a CSV spreadsheet?

Tags: python

If I have a program like this that requires inputted information from a user:

```
first_name = input("Enter First Name: ")
last_name = input("Enter Last Name: ")
```

How can I use data from a CSV sheet that contains first and last names to continuously enter and loop through the data, giving me outputs for all names?

In other words, I want my program to enter everyone's name from my CSV list and give me separate outputs (which are numbers that the program calculates for them) so that I don't need to do it all manually.

```
print(output)
Adam Smith, 378
John Smith, 673
Jane Doe, 289
...
```

My CSV data looks like this, with two columns for first and last name:

```
Adam | Smith
-------------
John | Smith
-------------
Jane | Doe
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the format of the data in the CSV file? Please mention this in your question, ideally with some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python `csv` module:

```py
import csv

path_to_file = ...  # Replace with the path to your csv file
file_content = csv.reader(path_to_file)

for row in file_content:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the names from a CSV file data like that using Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module like this:

```
import csv

with open('people_names.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    for first_name, last_name in csv.reader(csvfile):
        print(first_name, last_name)
        ... # Do calculations.
```